# FIFO class in Java

Tags: java, fifo

I want to implement FIFO through a class in Java.

Does such a class already exist? If not, how can I implement my own?

**NOTE**

I found a class here http://www.dcache.org/manuals/cells/docs/api/dmg/util/Fifo.html, but it doesn't contain dmg.util.*. I don't know if such a package even exists.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You're looking for any class that implements the [Queue interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html), excluding `PriorityQueue` and `PriorityBlockingQueue`, which do not use a FIFO algorithm.

Probably a [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) using `add` (adds one to the end) and `removeFirst` (removes one from the front and returns it) is the easiest one to use.

For example, here's a program that uses a LinkedList to queue and retrieve the digits of PI:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        char arr[] = {3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5,3,5,8,9};
        LinkedList<Integer> fifo = new LinkedList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            fifo.add (new Integer (arr[i]));

        System.out.print (fifo.removeFirst() + ".");
        while (! fifo.isEmpty())
            System.out.print (fifo.removeFirst());
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you *know* you only want to treat it as a queue (without the extra features of a linked list), you can just use the `Queue` interface itself:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        char arr[] = {3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5,3,5,8,9};
        Queue<Integer> fifo = new LinkedList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            fifo.add (new Integer (arr[i]));

        System.out.print (fifo.remove() + ".");
        while (! fifo.isEmpty())
            System.out.print (fifo.remove());
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

This has the advantage of allowing you to replace the underlying concrete class with any class that provides the `Queue` interface, without having to change the code too much.

The basic changes are to change the type of `fifo` to a `Queue` and to use `remove()` instead of `removeFirst()`, the latter being unavailable for the `Queue` interface.

Calling `isEmpty()` is still okay since that belongs to the `Collection` interface of which `Queue` is a derivative.

Comment: Why not make fifo be of type Queue<Integer> then?  Target the interface rather than the concrete implementation.

Comment: If you just want to iterate over the items in the queue in a FIFO manner without actually removing the items, then you can just do `for (Object item : queue)`, and it will iterate over them in a FIFO manner, at least on JDK 7 and with `ArrayDeQueue` and `LinkedList` impl.

Comment: Re **"You're looking for any class that implements the Queue interface"**. *This is not correct.* If someone is looking for FIFO, then they DON'T want `PriorityQueue` or `PriorityBlockingQueue`, because those don't do FIFO; they have a different ordering algorithm. On a lesser note, if someone is thinking **I want a simple FIFO queue**, then they likely don't want `SynchronousQueue`. Arguably, they don't even want any of the `Blocking` queues, though this is a more debatable claim. This reduces it down to two choices: `LinkedList` and `ArrayDeQueue`!

Comment: @ClickUpvote - pondering whether that syntax is a good thing or a bad thing. My first thought in seeing that line, is that I would think it was handling those items, e.g. removing them from the queue. IMHO anyone who uses that syntax should put a COMMENT above that code line, saying that this is peeking at the items, not removing them. Nevertheless, it is a handy trick to know.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve you must be new to java or java 7 if you think that syntax is removing things. that syntax is very common in java for looping over pretty much anything without removing them. its also recommended over for / while loops that just loop over something

Answer (score 19):

Try `ArrayDeque` or `LinkedList`, which both implement the `Queue` interface.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html

Comment: Yes, ArrayDeque and LinkedList have the .push method from Deque, which is what makes it usable as a Stack for FIFO.   ArrayDeque is more like a primitive array to use as a buffer whereas LinkedList is more like a data-store.

Comment: @djangofan stack is lifo

Answer (score 2):

[Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)s are First In First Out structures. You request is pretty vague, but I am guessing that you need only the basic functionality which usually comes out with Queue structures. You can take a look at how you can implement it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/queue.html).

With regards to your missing package, it is most likely because you will need to either download or create the package yourself by following that tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to implement your own FIFO Queue, just look at the interface [java.util.Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) and its implementations

Answer (score 1):

if you want to have a pipe to write/read data, you can use the http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedWriter.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LinkedBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) I use it in my projects. It's part of standard java and quite [easy to use](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/linkedblockingqueue.html)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you call FIFO these days since Queue is FILO, but when I was a student we used the **`Stack<E>`** with the simple *push*, *pop*, and a *peek*...  It is really that simple, no need for complicating further with Queue and whatever the accepted answer suggests.

Comment: Stack is defined as a last-in-first-out implementation while Queue implementations are first-in-first-out by default unless otherwise indicated with a comparator.

Comment: If  first in and last out always (un)occupies the same slot, then I didn't remember it properly. Otherwise, java.util.Stack simply doesn't work that way. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html