# Java ArrayList Adding objects --> Throw out old ones

Tags: java, arraylist, rotation

I have a class called "Transaction.java", and I have an ArrayList with the newest five transactions. So the size of this ArrayList should always be between 0 and 5.

When there's a new transaction, I have to rotate all the entries in this ArrayList. Entry 4 becomes entry 3, entry 3 becomes entry 2, entry 2 becomes entry 1, entry 1 becomes entry 0 and entry 0 becomes the new transaction.
The oldest one (the object with the index 4) is overwritten.

When trying to code this, I'm in trouble with ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions or NPEs because I do transactions.set(4, transactions.get(3));, even if there's nothing in transaction.get(3), and transaction.get(4) is empty as well!

This is a little snippet of my code:

```
for (int i =  4; i >= 0; i--) {
    try {
        if (i == 0) {
            latestTransactions.set(i, newTransaction);
        }
        else {
            latestTransactions.set(i, latestTransactions.get(i - 1));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) { // NPE / AIOOBE
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The exception is thrown 5 times (that's how big the for-loop is) and nothing's set in the ArrayList.

Please try to keep calm and understandable, I'm new in the buiseness ^^

Comment: `latestTransactions.get(i - 1)` - what will happen in the last iteration where `i` is 0?

Comment: You should have a look at Queue interface and implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580457/fifo-class-in-java

Comment: Any particular reason you are using `ArrayList` over bounded queues? They will be less prone to errors of sizing and easier to manage elements in your use case

Comment: An `ArrayList` is a very inefficient data structure for what you are trying to do with it. You'd be better off using a `LinkedList` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without the loop.

Assuming the ArrayList already contains 5 elements :

```
oldestElement = latestTransactions.remove(0); // this will remove the element at the 0 index
                                              // and decrement the index of all the others
```

Then

```
latestTransactions.add(newElement); // will add the new element at the end (index 4)
```

If the ArrayList can have less than 5 elements, you can write :

```
if (latestTransactions.size () >= 5) {
    oldestElement = latestTransactions.remove(0);
}
latestTransactions.add(newElement);
```

This will only remove the oldest element if the ArrayList already contains 5 elements, and add the new element at the end.

Comment: I have to assume that there's 0 up to 5 elements in the ArrayList. It does not always contain 5 elements though.

Answer (score -1):

```
Queue queue = new LinkedList();
queue.push(newTransaction);
setLatestTransaction(queue.pop());
```