# How to get a fixed sized Queue

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I am trying to create a fixed size Queue in java, I only want to store maximum 10 objects in the Queue. However, the queue keeps on storing/adding objects and ignoring the `if` condition.

my code:

```
Queue<Customer> sitt = new LinkedList<Customer>();
if(sitt.size() < 10) {
   System.out.println("Added");
   ((LinkedList<Customer>)sitt).offer(cust); 
} else {
   System.out.println("No space..");
}
```

I have another Runnable class, and I am running 22 threads. This condition should only add `0-9` objects of Customer class. However, the `sitt.size()` even exceed 20. Can anyone tell me what's the problem here? that even the `if` condition is being ignored.

P.S: The reason I am using Queue here, is because I have need FIFO.

Comment: why do you use a LinkedList? a simple Circular buffer would work, too

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580457/fifo-class-in-java

Comment: Since you are in a multithread scenario, you should put your if condition and adding in a synchronized block. Maybe the other threads check the queue size before the other threads add their elements.

Comment: @Karura91 yes it is within the synchronized block. and the `Added` prints for like 22 times. and `sitt.size()` keeps on increasing rather than stopping it 10.

@Domso I will check about Circular buffer.

@Stefan I am already using that way of Queue with LinkedList, but it ignores `if` condition.

Comment: @Nix I can't see anything wrong in this code. Could you post the code relevant to the synchronization too?

Comment: LinkedList isn't thread safe. Why not use a thread safe queue with a fixed size?

Comment: @PeterLawrey can you pleae explain, how linkedlist isn't thread safe?

Comment: @Nix A data structure has to be specifically implemented to be thread safe or it is not thread safe. LinkedList doesn't attempt to be thread safe.

Answer (score 5):

You can just use `LinkedBlockingQueue` from `java.util.concurrent` - it allows you to specify the fixed size for the queue.

```
new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(10);
```

Then you can insert values into it using `offer()` method which would do nothing and return `false` if queue is already full.

Comment: Or ArrayBlockingQueue or ConcurrentLinkedDeque or ConcurrentArrayQueue or ArrayDeque or LinkedBlockingDeque +1

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I am going to try all these. However, LinkedBlockingQueue<>(10); didn't solve the problem. I am going to update my Question with complete codes.

Comment: @Nix without looking at the code I assume that you're dealing with different instances of queues. That is - you might add item to one queue, but by mistake check the size of another.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, issue with such implementation - access to shared resource (queue) from multi threads without any syncronization between them. This leads to so called "race" conditions. In extremum case: all threads reads `size`, its equal 0. All threads executes condition's body and adds new elements.

I would either use some public solutions for "shared (blocking) circular queue", or implement it via thread-safe (via locking or else) "integer counter in array".

Comment: Not only race conditions, but also data races.