# Is there any java collection that allow "static capacity"?

Tags: java

I want to implement an algorithm as add entry first and get from the last postion.capacity of the collection should not be increased than initial capacity. Instead, it should overwrite entry with old one in the first position. Is There any ready-made java Collection available to succeed?

Thanks

Comment: So basically you want a FIFO(First in, First out) system? You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580457/fifo-class-in-java

Comment: thanks sir !!! i will try all your suggestions

Answer (score -1):

You can create your class using a Deque (for example, a ArrayDeque) and implement the required algorithms in it.